# Expecting nil but getting an interface with a nil value in return, which should be nil

Tags: go

Run it at
https://play.golang.org/p/sl12vfS9vP

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    err := run()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("%#v", err)
    }
}

func run() (err error) {
    return check()
}

func check() *Result {
    return nil
}

type Result struct {
    message string
}

func (result *Result) Error() string {
    return result.message
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is discussed on the [FAQ](https://golang.org/doc/faq#nil_error) and the [Go Traps](https://go-traps.appspot.com/#watchman) website:

> An interface value is nil only if the inner value and type are both unset, (nil, nil). In particular, a nil interface will always hold a nil type. If we store a pointer of type *int inside an interface value, the inner type will be *int regardless of the value of the pointer: (*int, nil). *Such an interface value will therefore be non-nil even when the pointer inside is nil.*

> (...)

> To return a proper nil error to the caller, the function must return an explicit nil:

```
func returnsError() error {
    if bad() {
        return ErrBad
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: @MX4399 `error` is an interface, and an interface value is `nil` only when both the type info and value pointer are `nil`. In your code, the result of `check()` is being *converted* to an interface type, setting the type info. If you want your code to work, add an explicit `if res == (*Result)(nil) { return nil }` to `run`.

Comment: The underlying problem is caused by go not allowing the return of a nil interface e.g return (interface{})(nil) or (nil)(nil) and at the same time not treating an explicit nil returned from a method with a pointer return as a nil in the next function which returns an interface. The result is that run() returns the type of check(), which is NOT an interface but implicitly supports 'error' and the explicit nil seems to be ignored. Further, every declared interface in go is also a type and should be distinct - here 'err' in check() becomes something else - a (*Result)(nil).

Comment: I edited my comment to ensure there is no misunderstanding - I am aware of the nil check for interfaces in go. The issue is that go transmutes the nil of type *X to an interface (*X)(nil), which does not evaluate to nil, instead of (nil)(nil) as is the intention in the code where an explicit nil is returned from the pointer returning function.

Answer (score 2):

Francesc Campoy Flores (from the Go team at Google) talked about this particular issue in [his presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B-r3Wf_I2Lk) at dotGo this year.

You can think an interface value has 2 parts; a type and a value. Therefore an interface of type `*Result` and value `nil` is not equal to an interface with both type and value `nil`.

You can fix your code by typing the `nil` in the comparison:

http://play.golang.org/p/E9kro7Fkbr

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    err := run()
    if err != (*Result)(nil) {
        fmt.Printf("%#v", err)
    }
}

func run() (err error) {
    return check()
}

func check() *Result {
    return nil
}

type Result struct {
    message string
}

func (result *Result) Error() string {
    return result.message
}
```

Comment: The goal is to be idiomatic and consistent in the error handling and treat any result from a method that supports the 'error' interface as an 'error' and nothing else by comparing it to nil without type assertions.

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell: don't mix interfaces and pointers/values when using direct or named return values in a function.

The goal is to create an error aggregator, e.g:

```
func checkStatus() *Result {
        r := &Result{}
        // ... do checks and append to r.message ...
        if r.message == "" {
            return nil
        }
        return r
}

func checkSomething() error {
    return runDiagnostics()
}

func runDiagnostics() *Result {
    ... do something
    // all ok 
    return nil
}

.. somewhere else .... (using named return values)
if err = checkStatus(); err != nil {
    return
}

.. this fails even when runDiagnostics() return nil ...
if err = checkSomething(); err != nil {
    ... err is always "something"
}
```

detailed check with a pointer http://play.golang.org/p/WPGy_ooXmP

detailed check with an interface http://play.golang.org/p/JjWxEj9WRX

solution with an error indicator http://play.golang.org/p/C30s49GiIN

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    err := run()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("%#v", err)
    }
}

func run() (err error) {
    _, err = check()
    return
}

func check() (*Result, error) {
    return nil, nil
}

type Result struct {
    message string
}

func (result *Result) Error() string {
    return result.message
}
```

solution with an interface http://play.golang.org/p/bFysxTFVIH

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    err := run()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("%#v", err)
    }
}

func run() (err error) {
    return check() // <-- for direct return or named return value an "interface{}" must be used
}

// uses an interface - Result
func check() Result {
    return nil
}

type Result interface {
    Error() string
}

type result struct {
    message string
}

func (result *result) Error() string {
    return result.message
}
```